# Python Convert an array to Wav

Tags: python, arrays, audio, fft

In Python, I have an array of floats representing the voltages of an analog signal.

Can anyone explain how I can change the array into a .wav format? I have seen [this](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html)
Do I first need to change the data format from [1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26] (for example) to 1.231.241.251.26 before adding the headers so that it's read correctly?
I eventually plan on using FFT on the values to derive the fundamental frequencies is there a better way to store the values in this case?

Thank you

Comment: you can check [wave](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) module

Comment: http://soledadpenades.com/2009/10/29/fastest-way-to-generate-wav-files-in-python-using-the-wave-module/

Comment: If you ultimately intend on performing an FFT then what's the point of writing out a wav file? One obvious problem is that your analog voltage levels are going to be lost as you'll need to rescale the data to -1.0 to 1.0 and wav has no native way of storing the scaling information (unless you embed it in a custom riff chunk).

Comment: @DreadfulWeather the documentation for the `wave` module is quite deficient in describing the expected data for `writeframes` for example.

Comment: My signal is biased and returns 10-bit results between 0 and 5.

Comment: I want to turn it into a wav so I can test the setup so far and see if the stream contains the correct information after I use an FFT

Answer (score 8):

If you know the sampling frequency of your signal and data is already scaled appropriately by `max(abs(data))` then you can do it very easily using [**scipy**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavf
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    samples = np.random.randn(44100)
    fs = 44100
    out_f = 'out.wav'

    wavf.write(out_f, fs, samples)
```

You can also use the standard [**wave**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) module.

Comment: is it possible to get wav from numpy without saving?

Comment: You can modify the scipy.io.wavfile.write function to get the bytes for the full wav file from numpy array https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/37b650e04f3bf49bc11cfcd18f2848ad4f957a0d/scipy/io/wavfile.py#L699